# How are JDBC drivers loaded without Class.forName() or System Properties?

Tags: java, jdbc, properties, system

I am trying to understand JDBC internals, specifically, how is my JDBC driver being loaded if 
1. I am not using Class.forName()
2. Checking for the jdbc.driver system property returns null.

I've tried checking my class path and printing the full list of system properties to the console for inspection as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver-java.sql.Driver- and https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/devguide/cdevdvlp40653.html

Below is the DBConnection constructor from DBConnection class

```
    `public DBConnection() {
        try {
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
            if (this.conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connection successful");
            }
        } catch(SQLException sqlex) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed");
        }
    }`
```

Below is main()

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DBConnection dbTest = new DBConnection();

        String sysPropsString = System.getProperties().toString();
        String[] propsArr = sysPropsString.split(",");

        for(String property : propsArr) {
            if (property.contains("class") && property.contains("path") 
                    && (property.contains("derby") || property.contains("drivers")))
                System.out.println(property);
        }
        System.out.println("***********************************");
        String sysDrivers = System.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
        System.out.println(sysDrivers);
    }
```

I expected to have the derby jdbc driver printed to the console from the System.getProperty() call OR to find it somewhere on the classpath, but I see neither. How is the derby driver being loaded?

Below is the output:

> Connection successful
>
> > java.class.path=/Users/aslotu/eclipse-workspace/Bullhorn/build/classes:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_cs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_de_DE.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_es.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_fr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_hu.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_it.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_ja_JP.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_ko_KR.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_pl.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_ru.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derbyLocale_zh_TW.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derby.jar
> >
> > ---
> >
> > null

Comment: As of Java 6 (JDBC 4), you have not needed `Class.forName` to load a JDBC driver. Instead, as noted in the [JDBC 4.0 and 4.1 features summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html), ***Autoloading of JDBC drivers.** In earlier versions of JDBC, applications had to manually register drivers before requesting Connections. With JDBC 4.0, applications no longer need to issue a Class.forName() on the driver name; instead, the DriverManager will find an appropriate JDBC driver when the application requests a Connection.*

Comment: I'm not sure `Class.forName()` is required anymore for newer versions of Java.  But to your question: SUGGESTION: Try loading the driver, then `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();`, and printing out all the URLs from `URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs()`

Comment: See also [Technotes - JAR File Specification - Service Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider).

Comment: When you print out `java.class.path` it ends with "...:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derby.jar". That looks like the Derby JDBC driver to me. Are you asking how your app *knows* to use that .jar file?

Comment: Whether or not `Class.forName` is needed in Java 6 depends on whether the driver declares `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` with the right class name(s), and whether or not the driver jar is on the initial classpath or not. Automatic driver loading does not work for drivers on a context classpath (a common example is a driver placed in `WEB-INF/lib` of a WAR; those are not automatically loaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`derby.jar` contains file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` which register `org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver`.

This work because `DriverManager` use `ServiceLoader`.

Comment: That's not really an answer as it's highly specific to a specific driver implementation.

Comment: @jwenting Isn't question specific to specific implementation?

Comment: Not as I read it. He's using Derby as an example but nowhere mentions it in the text of the question itself.

Comment: @jwenting I answered question how it was asked: "How is the derby driver being loaded?"

Comment: @jwenting It actually works the same for all JDBC drivers, the only difference is the exact classname in `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know. So the answer could have been better written by mentioning that rather than being specifically tailored towards a single driver.